# Search a particular values in a file and replace it with a string using Perl

Tags: perl

I have a log file which contain only urls. The file contains more than 300 000 lines. In each and every line there are some values in between the url. For example 20 lines

[image]

Here, in first 3 lines there is a value after "/code/ " something called "DMADCCA..."
and from 4th line there is a value after "/catalogue/" something called "APA01"
like that there are many line caotaine different values in different places.
what i need to do is replace those values with a string "SSSS" using perl script.
**Need perl script.**
**I need to match with pattern**
Can some one help me with it?

Comment: Do not insert image in the question, try to add the example file in the question itself.

Comment: You should show us (the code) what you have tried so far to achieve this.

Comment: Sounds like a job fer `sed`

Comment: *"Can some one help me with it?"* Please replace the images with text, so we can help you!!

Comment: Please find the link for file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Isa34L7hWju5BWsTWOItftwT71zMJsQN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Santhosh Thanks for providing the input file. Could you also update your question with the expected output after having run the script? That will help clarify your question

Comment: @Santhosh Note that the input file you provided does not correspond to the screenshot in the question. For example, there is no "DMADCCA..." in that file

Comment: Yes that is what I am telling. The file is very big and the values are changes all the time when I pull the file. (Values= Upper case, lower case alfabet, Numbers and special characters) That is why i need pattern based script.

Comment: Ok let me see if I understand: You want to replace anything in upper case after "/code/" until the next "/" with "SSSS"?

Comment: In that file where ever i see numbers i changed it to NNN using below script.
perl -pe 's/(\\/\\d+\\/)/\\/NNN\\//g' | perl -pe 's/(\\/\\/d+$)/\\/NNN/g'
I tried below script to change values as SSSS, but it doesn't work as expected.
sed -E 's#(.\*/(code|catalogue)/)\[^/\]\*#\\1SSSS#' file
Using above sed i can change some, but it will change some i never want to change.

Comment: for example you can see this
/goods-catalogue-service/v1/api/catalogue/NNN/code/ahvs123/categories
/auction-catalogue-service/v1/api/catalogue/CAT_CMC_KGF_10/catalogue-item/search-category-item
if you observe both above lines. I want to change ahvs123 and CAT_CMC_KGF_10 as SSSS. In this case in the first line after catalogue where NNN is there that is also changing as SSSS which i dont want. So only i am preferring perl script.
perl -pe 's/[A-Za-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/SSSS/g'
i tried this one also but it is changing entire line as SSSS.

Comment: I am not sure why you changed numbers to "NNN", please explain.

Comment: *"in the first line after catalogue where NNN is there that is also changing as SSSS which i dont want"* Please clarify why you do not want this

Comment: Every day when I receive these url are different than the previous. So if consider numbers as NNN then that is easy to match. So i can consider where ever NNN show that will be the number.

Comment: If NNN changes then it is difficult for me which one is number and which one is value.

Comment: I don't receive Same Numbers and Values all the time it will differ in the urls. It Can be any number/Values where i receive in the urls.

Comment: @Santhosh We may consider continuing the discussion in chat, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95937/why-must-we-avoid-discussions-in-comments . You can contact me on Google Chat if you like

Comment: Ok Sure. Google chat also ok.

Comment: You can find my gmail id in my profile

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's#(.*/(code|catalogue)/)[^/]*#\1SSSS#' file
```

Use greed and alternation to replace the value following the last occurrence of `/code/` or `/catalogue/` on a line.

Other keys than `code` or `catalogue` may be inserted/appended, however they must take into account the greedy `.*` that restricts them to the last such occurrence on a line and so their ordering may need to be adjusted.

N.B. The substitution command uses alternative delimiters (`#`).

Aside: `tesseract OHfg9.png - -l eng 2>/dev/null|sed '/\S/!d' >file` provided the test data in text format `file`.

Comment: **Need perl script.** 
**I need to match with pattern**